PDF knitting does not work on Quarto (xelatex, „ERROR: tlmgr returned a non zero status code“ „TLPDB: not a directory, not loading“)
I want to create a PDF from a Quarto document, but I get an error message.
Rendering PDF
running xelatex - 1
command xelatex not found, attempting install
finding package for xelatex
> 1 package to install
> installing xelatex (1 of 1)
ERROR: tlmgr returned a non zero status code
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /home/zuk/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!


Stack trace:
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /home/zuk/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!

    at Object.onComplete (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:91548:64)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:183:11)
    at async renderFiles (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:77075:16)
    at async renderProject (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:77394:25)
    at async serveProject (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:97502:24)
    at async Command.fn (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:98181:9)
    at async Command.execute (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:8104:13)
    at async quarto (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:115002:5)
    at async file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:115020:9

I don't know what the reason is and I haven't found anything here or on DuckDuckGo.
I changed the Typeset in the Project Options from pdfLaTeX into XeLaTeX. That doesn't work.
I use the latest R and RStudio version.
R: 4.4.0
RStudio: 2024.04.1 Build 748
Quarto 1.4.553
Fixing this error is very important for me, because I want to write my bachelor thesis with Quarto. Knitting PDFs is necessary for this.
If I create the folder /home/zuk/texmf I got this error message:
ERROR: tlmgr returned a non zero status code
TLPDB: Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/zuk/texmf!
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!


Stack trace:
TLPDB: Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/zuk/texmf!
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!

    at Object.onComplete (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:91548:64)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:183:11)
    at async renderFiles (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:77075:16)
    at async renderProject (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:77394:25)
    at async serveProject (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:97502:24)
    at async Command.fn (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:98181:9)
    at async Command.execute (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:8104:13)
    at async quarto (file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:115002:5)
    at async file:///usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.js:115020:9


Does the folder /home/zuk/texmf exist?

unrelated to the error, but xelatex is a bad choice for typesetting any document. If you don't need special characters, I would use pdflatex, it is much faster. If you need unicode support, then I would prefer lualatex, it is much more powerful than xelatex and causes much less problems with fonts etc.

The folder /home/zuk/texmf does not exist. Do I need to install anything else?

Can you try to just create the folder?

I have pasted the result above.

Honestly I don't know, how I change the typesetting engine.

I (re)installed tinytex via the terminal, then it worked.
